# Rejecting an Acception

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

What happens when you answer someone's question, they accept your answer, but then you find out that your answer is wrong and the asker hasn't revoked the check mark.

Could there be some way for the owner of the answer to remove the check mark?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can correct your answer... Take it as an opportunity to educate others who might have made the same mistake you did as to **1)** why your original answer was wrong, and **2)** what the better solution is.

Comment: Spot on             .

Comment: True, but in the case an answer can't be found or someone else actually submitted a better answer before I learn what went wrong, I would like to be able to say "Thank you, but this isn't the answer you are looking for."

Comment: What happens if you delete a correct answer? Chaos?

Comment: @Ian: you can't delete an accepted answer. I tried... ;-)
@toast: it's too late for that - the person who accepted the answer presumably already has put it into practice. Ideally, he'll come back at some point and read your explanation of why he shouldn't do what you already suggested; at that point, he could also Accept a different answer. 'Till then, you should do the best you can to correct any misconceptions.

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, I just don't like sitting around with what feels like undeserved rep.

Comment: Yeah, i can appreciate that. The ability to *transfer* accepted status has been requested in the past (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away), but i'm not too enthusiastic about it; IMHO, it's still the OP's to give or take. 'Till then, you can try to make your answer deserving...

Comment: You may feel that your answer is not all it can be, but the person who accepted your answer presumably found it to be the most helpful answer they could get. I think that decision should remain with the person asking the question.

Comment: @Robert: this is a principled stance, but exceedingly impractical - to the point of being outright *harmful* - when the goal is to provide a helpful, useful answer to the countless readers who will follow. Consider the case - which I faced just yesterday - of an answer that was correct *when written* but due to changing circumstances has become useless or flat-out incorrect: do you stubbornly refuse to change out of respect for the long-departed asker, or revise out of respect for the increasingly-confused stream of new readers?

Comment: @shog9 - ah sorry, I'm not saying that answers shouldn't be edited to keep them up to date, they absolutely SHOULD (though I'd also like to keep the 'history' so people can get info for old versions of software), I was talking about being able to 'reject' the award from the OP - it helped them at the time presumably, and the their acceptance of the answer reflects that.

Comment: @Robert: Ah, yes, that makes more sense.