# Why is there no justice in the world? (Or, "Let enlightened fellows pass the baton.")

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow Accepted Answer Recipient to Give It Away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away)

Let me start with a short story:

Several years ago a car in front of me freaked when he saw a police car on the side of the road and braked suddenly. The cop pulled me over and gave me a ticket for "following too closely". I went to court (foolishly on my own) and gave a great many good arguments about why this was nonsense, not the least of which was because the only reason I was temporarily too close was due to the presence of the police car.

The officer's testimony was that I was "one car length" behind the other car. That he timed it and it at 1.4 seconds between the back of his bumper and the front of mine. The judge said "One car length is too close" and kicked me out. Two minutes after I left the court room I did the math to realize that 1.4s at 65mph is 123 feet. I was not "one car length" away.

Now for a bit of more on-topic whining:

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676765/javascript-convert-a-string-to-regular-expression/4676794#4676794) at the same time as another user. His answer was wrong in several ways. I posted a comment pointing out the flaws. He fixed them. He got the "Accepted" flag. THERE IS NO JUSTICE! :p

So, on to the suggestion:

If one user with *n* thousand rep gets the "accept" flag, but thinks another answer is better, wouldn't it be nice if that user could pass the baton and switch the accept to another answer that he deems more correct?

The person asking the question is (often) more confused on the topic than those answering the question. Those answering the question are therefore likely to be in a better position to judge the better answer than the OP himself/herself.

We're trusted to edit questions, edit answers, and vote up answers all in the quest to create clear questions and answers that help the world. Why not let us gladly give the credit to the more worthy answer?

*Yes, this suggestion is a duplicate of* [Allow Accepted Answer Recipient to Give It Away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away), *but it clearly has much more passion behind it.* :)

Comment: +1 I think it's a good idea, and I've had a cop do the same thing to me, only he was passing a line of cars and the car in front of me backed off the gas as soon as he saw the cop in his side mirror, putting me too close. I got pulled over, and got to spend about two hours as he tore apart the rental car I was driving because "he smelled pot". I was so pissed.