# Removing the accepted status from a answer

Tags: discussion, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow Accepted Answer recipient to give it away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away)

Surely this should be changed or allow me to delete [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity/2286334#2286334).

Clearly my answer is wrong (there is a answer just after it with 14 up votes) , why not allow me to remove my answer so that people in future can benefit , instead of every new person down voting me causing me to loose rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your answer has been accepted, then the op has indicated that they found it useful.  Whether or not it is correct is to an extent, besides the point, as such I don't see any reason *why* you would want to delete it.  The community has already indicated that they feel another answer is better, through upvoting it.  Removing your answer, isn't going to make that one the accepted answer.

If it's to prevent future downvotes, then an obvious option would be to edit your answer and indicate that one of the subsequent answers has offered extra information that has changed your mind.  In most cases, that would be enough.  You could also comment to the OP that asked the question, suggesting that they change their accepted answer (although in this case it seems unlikely to work, since they seem to have *gone away*).

What I find odd about your request is that you've also provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-property-applied/1220848#1220848) on a different question, which hasn't been accepted, has a similar number of downvotes and *could* have been deleted, but hasn't been.

Comment: Thanks will go the route of editing the old answer , your explanation re : what the OP found useful vs what the community found useful makes sense, I had not looked at it in that way. The only reason I did not delete the other answer referenced is because I forgot about it ( I have deleted it now) , I got a notice about the one in my post yesterday which made me re look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Flag your answer and explain why it should be deleted. A moderator can still delete accepted answers.

Changing the accepted answer is something only the user who asked the question can do, moderators can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

There ought to be a flag that allows people to recommend an alternative answer be accepted for a given question. The user who asked the question could then be notified when the number of flags reaches a certain threshold to invite them to review their decision.

Comment: Just comment on the question. In the meantime, be sure to downvote the accepted answer if it's wrong. An accepted answer with a negative score is a fairly good indicator that readers really ought to scroll down.

Comment: It's not about wrong accepted answers, it's about whether there's a better answer. I wouldn't want to downvote an answer that was valid and helpful, but possibly not as good as another.

Comment: As for commenting, no harm in doing that as well as flagging - doesn't have to be either/or.

Answer (score 0):

Moderators can now delete accepted answers (this is a fairly recent feature).

Before this was done, or until the moderators see your flag, you can edit your answer to just say something like

> I thought this was a global setting, but this turns out to be wrong. Read and upvote [Mattias's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity/2673680#2673680) instead”.

And make it community wiki, because votes on an accepted answer don't change the display and gaining or losing reputation on it would be meaningless.