# I answered a question incorrectly, but it was accepted. How can I delete it

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow Accepted Answer recipient to give it away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away)

I answered a question incorrectly.

Bizarrely, it was accepted.

Now I can't delete it.

Since I don't stand by the answer and I know it's incorrect, is there a way that it can be unaccepted so that I can delete it? SO users will be less inclined to offer a *correct* answer if they see that one has already been accepted.

Comment: Notify the question author and ask for an unaccept.

Answer (score 10):

The best solution would be editing your answer to fix it.

If you don't want to do that for some reason, comment on it asking the OP to un-accept it.
If that doesn't help (e.g. because the OP stopped using SO or doesn't care) flag it so a moderator can delete it.

Answer (score 7):

You can flag it for deletion, a moderator will review it and delete the answer if he or she agrees.

Use the 'other' option and make your case.